# Saved Queries limit in a Hue Project

Tags: hue

Hue web interface provides the facility of saving 'Hive Queries'. We can also create projects and get the organized storage of Queries.
Does project-wise Query storage have any limitations on the number of queries we can save? By default it shows that it can save only 100 queries. How can we extend this limit i.e. store more than 100 queries in a project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit on the number of queries. You can filter the names of the query or open the /home page of Hue to see them all.

Comment: Convinced on the point that there is no limit on the number of queries. The actual problem is that queries are disappearing from /home -- > My Projects/ Dafault. I can see that there are  125 queries under my saved queries list but there are only 96 queries under Dafault section of My projects. Even if I deleted, recreated and saved some of the queries but newly added queries replaced some of the previously added queries under default section of My Projects. Any thoughts?